# Is it possible to make a SurfaceView transparent without setZOrderOnTop(true)?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, surfaceview, glsurfaceview

I need to make my libGDX GlSufraceView transparent with opportunity to add some android view above. Earlier I used code below:

```
if (graphics.getView() instanceof SurfaceView) {
    GLSurfaceView glView = (GLSurfaceView) graphics.getView();
    glView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
    glView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

However, this code does not give me possibility to add android views above. After a short research I found replacement: `glView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);` .
With that line of code, I can show any view above surface, but transparent became black.

I thought that this problem was due to the fact that my code was launched after setRenderer(...). After I found method which contains setRenderer(...) in gdx-backend-android. Few moments later I downloaded libGDX sources and add lines before setRenderer(...), but unfortunately it didn't help, situation still the same.

The code, which I was trying:

1)

```
GLSurfaceView20 view = new GLSurfaceView20(application.getContext(), resolutionStrategy, config.useGL30 ? 3 : 2);
view.setZOrderOnTop(true);

if (configChooser != null)
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(configChooser);
else
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(config.r, config.g, config.b, config.a, config.depth, config.stencil);

view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

view.setRenderer(this);
view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

return view;
```

2)

```
GLSurfaceView20 view = new GLSurfaceView20(application.getContext(), resolutionStrategy, config.useGL30 ? 3 : 2);
if (configChooser != null)
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(configChooser);
else
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(config.r, config.g, config.b, config.a, config.depth, config.stencil);

view.setZOrderOnTop(true);
view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

view.setRenderer(this);
return view;
```

3)

```
GLSurfaceView20 view = new GLSurfaceView20(application.getContext(), resolutionStrategy, config.useGL30 ? 3 : 2);

if (configChooser != null)
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(configChooser);
else
    view.setEGLConfigChooser(config.r, config.g, config.b, config.a, config.depth, config.stencil);

view.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
view.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true);
view.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

view.setRenderer(this);
return view;
```

Also I found few topics about that theme, but there is no right answer. 
Is is possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's impossible, but fortunately, I found the solution.
I just replaced surface view in libgdx android backend sources with texture view.
Also I added one line in my code, for make my texture view transparent:

```
view.setOpaque(false);
```

Advantages of my solution:

- Increased FPS (130 instead of 55)
- Flexibility

Now, I can use my libGDX fragment view as any ordinary views. I can place it between android views and so on.

Comment: can you explain this a little bit more please? I am havine the same issue

Comment: I downloaded android backend source from github and replaced GLSurface view with this class: https://gist.github.com/wasabeef/ac7454ed01deb99afb6c.

Comment: If you want I can upload modified source code to github

Comment: There you can download compiled android backend with texture view support: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TfcsmTPI6BFZNkcbTaADAR55FLFqa42X/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can check how it works in my app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rdgames.browsball&hl=en.

Comment: This jar file already contains setOpaque line, you just need to copy it to your lib folder and implement it in gradle file